# Add column to dataframe based on column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes: subhalo_field and halo_field

```
  halo_index
0 3447
1 3447
2 5286
3 3124
4 3124
...
```

So halo_index column values are not unique.
My other dataframe is halo_field:

```
  index rh
0 3447  2
1 5286  5
2 3124  10
...
```

halo_field.index values are unique and featuring in subhalo_field.halo_index column (some of then a lot of times). I want to add column to subhalo_field dataframe (first one) so it looks like this:

```
  halo_index rh
0 3447       2
1 3447       2
2 5286       5
3 3124       10
4 3124       10
...
```

Can you help me do that please?

Comment: `df1.merge(df2,left_on='halo_index',right_on='index',how='left')`

Comment: Or df1.halo_index.map(df2.set_index('index').rh)

Comment: Thank you, actually this worked: subhalo_field['rh']=subhalo_field.halo_index.map(halo_field.set_index('index').rh)